# How do I generate an MsBuild itemList from another item list based on the current item's directory name?

Tags: msbuild

i'm taking a list of files `*.config` and copying them to a list of directories. The directories are relative to a path `C:\branches\` have a name and then the name.UnitTest.

so the copy looks like this without being refactored/batched:

```
<Target Name="CopyClientConfigs">

<ItemGroup>
    <ClientConfigDestinations Include="$(LocalSourcePath)\Module1\Module1.UnitTest\;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\Module2\Module2.UnitTest\;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\CommonControls\Module3\Module3.UnitTest\;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\Administration\Module4\Module4.UnitTest\;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\IndividualControls\Configuration\Module5\Module5.UnitTest\" />
    <ClientConfigs
    Include="$(ClientConfigPath)\*.config"
    Exclude="$(ClientConfigPath)\P*.config" >
    </ClientConfigs>
</ItemGroup>
<Copy
        SourceFiles="@(ClientConfigs)"
        DestinationFolder="%(ClientConfigDestinations.FullPath)"
        />
```

What I want is to be able to use this ItemGroup

```
<ItemGroup>
<MyModules Include="$(LocalSourcePath)\Module1;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\Module2;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\CommonControls\Module3;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\Administration\Module4;
    $(LocalSourcePath)\IndividualControls\Configuration\Module5"
/>
```

So the task would be like

```
Copy
        SourceFiles="@(ClientConfigs)"
        DestinationFolder="%(ClientConfigDestinations.FullPath)\*.UnitTest\"
        />
```

Or better

```
Copy
        SourceFiles="@(ClientConfigs)"
        DestinationFolder="%(ClientConfigDestinations.FullPath)\%(ClientConfigDestinations.NameOnly).UnitTest\"
        />
```

How do I refactor or properly batch this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Target Name="CopyClientConfigsBatched" Outputs="%(MyModules.FullPath)">
    <Message Text="@(MyModules -> '%(FullPath)\%(FileName).UnitTest')"/>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClientConfigs
    Include="$(ClientConfigPath)\*.config"
    Exclude="$(ClientConfigPath)\P*.config" >
    </ClientConfigs>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ClientConfigs)" DestinationFolder="@(MyModules -> '%(FullPath)\%(FileName).UnitTest')"
     SkipUnchangedFiles="true"/>
</Target>
```

target batching seems to have done it!

Comment: Similar to this you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701177/how-to-always-execute-a-target-in-msbuild/3714585#3714585.

Comment: @Sayed thanks, interesting link. I don't think this will apply in my situation, as my team does not seem to embrace/allow any customizing of the project files, so the .proj code here is in a project that doesn't actually do any building, just refreshes my environment from the master.

Answer (score 9):

If I read your question right, I *think* you are trying to do a cross-product copy:  copy all items in one ItemGroup to all the folders in a different group.

I actually have a neat target that I use to do this, as I hate the way TeamBuild puts all the binaries into a single folder - I want projects to be able to specify that their output is a "bundle" and that the output will also be copied to one or more locations.

To do this, I have two itemgroups: BundleFiles (which is the set of files that I want to copy) and BundleFolders which are the set of folders that I want to copy to.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BundleOutDir Include="FirstFolder;SecondFolder" />
    <BundleFiles Include="file1;file2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My target then contains two tasks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesByDirsCrossProduct Include="@(BundleFiles)">
        <BundleOutDir>%(BundleOutDir.FullPath)</BundleOutDir>
    </FilesByDirsCrossProduct>
</ItemGroup>
```

This creates an uber item group containing a cross product of files by folders.

The copy is then pretty simple:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesByDirsCrossProduct)"
    DestinationFiles="@(FilesByDirsCrossProduct -> '%(BundleOutDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)' ) "
    SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

This then copies the files to the folder specified within their meta data.

My target is actually a little more clever in that I can declare that bundles will go to sub folders and/or I can rename a file during the copy through meta data, but that's a different story

Comment: +1 this looks pretty close, but I need my destination folder to be a subfolder... `FirstFolder\FirstFolder.UnitTestFolder` and I don't think `%(BundleOutDir)\*.UnitTestFolder\%(Filename)%(Extension)` will function

Comment: yeah I get illegal characters in path when I try it that way.

Comment: Interesting approach for copying a set of files to a set of locations. I like it.

Comment: Hmm - Should be simple to do in the copy.  You don't need a "*" as you are only working with a single item  (when you see %(item) think  of a "foreach" loop doing a single action on an item)

DestinationFiles="@(FilesByDirsCrossProduct -> '%(BundleOutDir)\%(BundleOutDir).UnitTestFolder\%(Filename)%(Extension)' ) "

Comment: @Peter, if when you said a single item you mean the configs item, no I'm copying 3 config files. If you meant the target, i'm having trouble following your comment. Does it still apply having seen my answer?

Comment: @Maslow:  Y - I think we are confusing each other - i was responding to your "+1 this looks pretty close.." comment where I saw you write "%(BundleOutDir)*.UnitTestFolder"  - I was trying to explain how I think of a statement that contains %(xyz) - it does work on the entire set of "xyz" things - but it passes each item into the task one at a time.  When I see @(xyz) in a task, it helps me to think that its like passing an array into the task